Why does not index (S&P500, NASDAQ, Dow Jones, etc), use liquidity?
Stock indexes such as SP500, NASDAQ, Dow Jones, etc all try to capture the temperature of the market. If the market cap of the companies in the market increase, the index increase.
But, imagine a theoretical situtation where the market tanks in this way: liquidity decrease, but the prices remains high (few wants to sell). In that case, the index remains the same or even increase, even though the market tanks.
Therefore if the index, mirrored the turnover in the market, it would better capture the temperature of the stock market.
My question is: are there indexes that are based on the turnover, i.e. liquidity x price, instead of only price?

How would the market tank when nobody wants to sell their stocks?
